# python classes using functions of other classes

Tags: python

```
class plc:
    def __init__(self,name,zones):
        self.list_zones=[]
        self.name= name
        for zone in zones:
            self.list_zones.append(zone)
    def actie(self):
        print self.name

class zone:
    def __init__(self,name,conveyors):
        self.list_conveyors=[]
        self.naam = name
        for conveyor in conveyors:
        self.list_conveyors.append(conveyor)
    def actie(self):
        print self.name

class conveyor:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.naam = name
    def actie(self):
        print self.name



if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_conveyors_zone_1= []
    list_conveyors_zone_1.append(conveyor(1))
    list_conveyors_zone_1.append(conveyor(2))
    list_conveyors_zone_1.append(conveyor(3))


    list_conveyors_zone_2 = []
    list_conveyors_zone_2.append(conveyor(4))
    list_conveyors_zone_2.append(conveyor(5))


    list_zone_plc_1 = []
    list_zone_plc_1.append(zone(10,list_conveyors_zone_1))
    list_zone_plc_1.append(zone(20,list_conveyors_zone_2))


    plc_1 = plc(1,list_zone_plc_1)
    plc_1.list_zones[1].list_conveyors[1].actie()
```

Hey, i would like to program this so the a.ctie() funtion of the conveyor also runs the actie() of the zone the conveyor is an element of and then this zone runs the actie() of the plc he is in.

how can i do this?

Comment: [look](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing a class that has an `__init__` and one other function, that's almost always not a class and should be written as data or just plain functions.

```
conveyors = dict()
conveyors.['zone1'] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
conveyors.['zone2'] = [5,6]
conveyors.['plc1'] = [10, 20]
```

this allows you to reference things very easily. If I want to know the name of the third conveyor in zone1:

```
conveyors['zone1'][2]
```

if I need to get the names of all conveyors belts then:

```
for zone in conveyors:
    for belt in conveyors[zone]:
        print(belt)
```

There are no classes, the code is greatly more readable, and you don't need so many intermediate values. Even using more descriptive names (such as "belt") help the reader.

People who come from a Java background are used to forcing everything to be a class because Java requires it. If you write Python like it were Java, it will not be good.

Comment: There is a good video presentation from PyCon 2012 called [Stop Writing Classes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0)

Answer (score -1):

You need two things: 1) each `conveyor` object needs to store a reference to a `zone` object, and each `zone` object needs to store a reference to a `plc` object. 2) `conveyor.actie` simply needs to call the method on its stored `zone` reference, and likewise for the `zone` and its `plc`.

One way to do that is to update each zone passed to a plc, and each conveyor passed to a zone.

```
class Plc:
    def __init__(self, name, zones):
        self.list_zones = list(zones)
        self.name = name
        for zone in zones:
            zone.plc = self

    def actie(self):
        print self.name

class Zone:
    def __init__(self, name, conveyors):
        self.list_conveyors = list(conveyors)
        self.naam = name
        for c in conveyors:
            c.zone = self

    def actie(self):
        print self.name
        if hasattr(self, 'plc'):
            self.plc.actie()

class Conveyor:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.naam = name

    def actie(self):
        print self.name
        if hasattr(self, 'zone'):
            self.zone.actie()
```

The above takes the approach that the container is responsible for adding itself to the contained object. Another approach is pass the container to the `__init__` method of each contained object and have it update itself.

Regardless of how the references are put into place, it's just matter of calling the container's `actie` method from with the contained object's method.